# How to add custom Header Data in Joomla

Tags: json, joomla, joomla3.0

I m trying to make json response for android application.

Here is the code

```
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setMimeEncoding('application/json');
$document->setCharset('utf-8');
```

The above code is working fine. but when I add the following code it does not generate any response.

```
$temp['TOKEN'] = "abc";
$document->setHeadData($temp);
```

I want to get the same result which can be achieved by followin code.

```
header('TOKEN:abc');
```

I cant use the `header()` method in my code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// For Joomla 2.5 - 4.0 (deprecated)
JResponse::setHeader('token', 'ABC');

// For Joomla 3.1+ (recommended)
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->setHeader('token', 'ABC');
```

Just make sure you are not closing the application in the component, or it won't have a chance to send these.

If you do, you'll have to flush the headers manually:

```
// For Joomla 2.5 - 4.0 (deprecated)
JResponse::sendHeaders();
JFactory::getApplication()->close();

// For Joomla 3.1+ (recommended)
$app->sendHeaders();
$app->close();
```

Note:

If the page has been requested with the `?format=json`, you don't have to set up the `JDocument` as application have used `JDocumentJson` with proper mime and charset.

Tip:

Check out [`com_ajax`](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/staging/components/com_ajax/ajax.php) which assists in building JSON responses and handling exceptions.